# Notepad++ Multiple search

Tags: python, search, notepad++

I am using the "Find in Files" (Ctrl +Shift +F) functionality of Notepad++ to search occurrences of a string in text files.
My text files (.sql) are located in sub-folders of a directory (for instance "Views" and "MaterializedViews" below):

```
C:\users\Schema Export\schema_name\Views  
C:\users\Schema Export\schema_name\ MaterializedViews
```

For instance, a click on "Find All" for "cust_account" (in the directory:"C:\users\Schema Export\schema_name\") gives me in the "Find result" screen of Notepad:

```
C:\users\Schema Export\schema_name\Views\SM.sql (2 hits)  
C:\users\Schema Export\schema_name>\Views \V_ACCOUNT.sql (8 hits)  
C:\users\Schema Export\schema_name\Views \V_ACCOUNT_rework.sql (8 hits)
```

A new search for "pos_row_id" for instance, gives me:

```
C:\users\Schema Export\schema_name\Views\V_ACCOUNT.sql (2 hits)  
C:\users\Schema Export\schema_name\Views\V_ACCOUNT_rework.sql (2 hits)  
C:\users\Schema Export\schema_name\Views\V_HUB_REFER.sql (1 hit)
```

In collapse mode, I now get two lines in the search window:

```
Search "pos_row_id" (5 hits in 3 files)  
Search "cust_account" (22 hits in 4 files)
```

I would like to automatize this search to get in one shot something like:

```
Search value1 (x1 hits in y1 files), where value1 is "pos_row_id" in example above,  
Search value2 (x2 hits in y2 files), where value2 is "cust_account" in example above,  
Search value3 (x3 hits in y3 files), etc.  
Search value4 (x4 hits in y4 files) 
Search value5 (x5 hits in y5 files) 
Search value6 (x6 hits in y6 files)
(..)
```

My first idea was to record a macro and update it (duplicating the codes from the existing with my different values, value1, value2, etc.)
Unfortunately the macro code is not generated in the "shortcuts.xml" file (there are many threads on this topic…)

Is there any other possibility (maybe with a python script) to retrieved in one shot from a list of values all the search result as describe above?

Thanks!

Comment: You should take a look at the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) if you are unsure how to ask / comment (I see you tried to edit my post to notify me for clarification). I'll update my answer, but please comment next time instead of editing if you have something to ask.

Comment: And you're probably getting a syntax error because you are not running last python version (which I've specified in my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using python 3.6.2. I'm first storing the values into a dict, then summing the hits found when printing.

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict


def find_all(*args):
    matches = defaultdict(dict)
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):  # walk through all files in all subdirectories
        for file in files:
            with open(os.path.join(subdir, file)) as f:
                data = f.read()
                for arg in args:
                    c = data.count(arg)  # count the number of hits in this file
                    if c > 0:  # if positive, add it to the matches
                        matches[arg][os.path.join(subdir, file)] = c

    return matches


search = find_all('test', 'file')  # your search keys here
for key in search:
    print(f"Search {key} ({sum(search[key].values())} hits in {len(search[key])} files),")
```

`'test'` and `'file'` are just random search keys that I've inserted in the function to test it, modify those with your search items. You could also pass an iterable to the function, such a `list` of words to search.